Local client requests fail with 400 response (WebChannelConnection RPC 'Listen' stream transport error)
I'm trying to integrate with Firestore for the first time on my Next.js project, and everything is working on a local emulator. But when I try to make any request to my live database from my local environment, I see two requests to Listen, the second of which fails with a 400 response, and both requests are constantly retried for some time:
// 200
https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?VER=8&database=projects%2Fsocialgames-c36c8%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=76067&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&zx=1icfdzdauapt&t=1

// 400
https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Listen/channel?gsessionid=ItMqy6u1yzZuNQiUX0fh1R58h08ZEU8anXMjDYWwzmA&VER=8&database=projects%2Fsocialgames-c36c8%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&RID=rpc&SID=vIrIIwY2WdPs8oOAW9kG7w&AID=0&CI=0&TYPE=xmlhttp&zx=20g3zdhqv4h7&t=1



This is my code:
'use client';

import { initializeApp, getApps } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { initializeFirestore} from 'firebase/firestore';
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseconfig';

export const firebaseApp =
  getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApps()[0];
export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
export const db = initializeFirestore(firebaseApp);

import { User as AuthUser } from 'firebase/auth';
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  doc,
  getDoc,
} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '@/lib/firebase/clientApp';
import User, { buildUser } from '@/lib/model/user/user';

export async function getOrCreateUser(authUser: AuthUser): Promise<User> {
  // This promise rejects with an error
  const user = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', authUser.uid));

  ...
}

I've triple checked the document path is correct - I also tried querying all docs from the 'users' collection, as well as adding a doc, but the results are the same. From another question I tried setting experimentalForceLongPolling: true but that didn't change anything either. I've also updated my security rules to blanket allow all requests, and no dice. The Cloud Firestore console does show a bit of traffic to my backend, but I'm not sure how else to debug this. What am I doing wrong?

I think I found my problem - my project apparently didn't have a default database. I used the web console to set things up, and I created a database with an arbitrary identifier. When I created another database, leaving the value of the "Database ID" field as "(default)", that new database works correctly.
